# zip file download issue

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, ftp

I am unable to download .zip file using filezilla or flashfxp, whenever I try downloading the file to our windows7 machine it gets stuck and keep on downloading until I manually kill the download process.

Does anyone facing the same issue, is this a bug?

Comment: Is this a particular zip file or all zip files ?

Comment: All zip files are having the same issue.

Comment: Corporate network?  Maybe security policies?

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't think this has to do with zip format. Are you able to download other files? You need to have permission to read the file.
You can use chmod to change the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

i can download and upload .zip - files to and from my FTP-server here ...

is the file accessible if you move it into your webservers docroot and download it via a browser? If no, your file-privileges are screwed up, try giving them 755